# Domain name cannot be used in Cloudfront after deletion of distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudfront

I have created a cloudfront distribution and have set the alternate domain name to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), with an associated certificate. I have then deleted the distribution, without removing the alternate domain from the distribution first, and tried to create another distribution with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as the alternate domain name again. This time it fails and says:

> One or more aliases specified for the distribution includes an incorrectly configured DNS record that points to another CloudFront distribution. You must update the DNS record to correct the problem.

This does not happen if I remove the alternate domain name from the distribution before deleting it.

Is there anyway to clear this error so that I can set [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as the alternate domain name for a new distribution?

Edit: The domain name is managed through Google Domains

Comment: Is this a Route53-managed domain?

Comment: I had to delete the CNAME entries for the certificate from GoDaddy and then it worked, I am not sure how that is related.. but if the certificate is associated with the alternate domain name it gives the error

Comment: @gshpychka No, it is managed through Google Domains. I have updated the question now.

Comment: Try this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-move

Comment: My domain service was Namecheap and I removed the CNAME entries from Namecheap and it worked.  @NgenCMS solution was worked

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar case, the only difference being that the domain name was managed through Route 53 and AWS Certificate Manager, not Google Domains.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-move suggests checking via AWS CLI for the conflicting aliases, however, the result of the command was that there are no conflicting aliases:

```sh
$ aws cloudfront list-conflicting-aliases --alias *** --distribution-id ***
{
    "ConflictingAliasesList": {
        "MaxItems": 100,
        "Quantity": 0,
        "Items": []
    }
}
```

So this was a dead-end.

The actual solution for me was… to wait: the next day, after around 16 hours, out of nowhere I was able to add the alternate domain successfully.

My *guess* is that we see that the old distribution is removed, while what we don't see, some leftovers (like the alternate domain association to the old distribution) are still pending for deletion.

Comment: I'm about 14 hours in the waiting period and still getting the same error. When checking my CNAME from the registrar, I can see that the domain was updated to point to the new distribution domain. My AWS certificate has a wildcard for the subdomain so that shouldn't be the issue. The command you provided is throwing an error for me (InvalidArgument) so I can't confirm using that. I guess my only option is to continue waiting.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem with the distribution itself. It looks like distribution creation is checking the domain name, and it sees that it's set to another (not existing) distribution.
[image]

1. Remove a CNAME record pointing to an old or removed distribution in your DNS provider.
2. Wait until the cache is refreshed (which can take from minutes to days).
3. Try again.

Comment: I had this issue with SST when deleting a website stack and trying to create it again, the cloudfront distribution changed, I am managing my DNS in an external provider (not Route53). Deleting the old CNAME entry from my DNS and deploying again fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**CloudFront refuses to accept an alias that is already an existing CNAME pointing somewhere else, another *.cloudfront.net hostname.**

The error message is not exactly helpful, but here is what was happening in my case:

1. I had a CNAME foo.example.com pointing at foo1.cloudfront.net (foo1 is a mock value, obviously)
2. I removed the CloudFront distribution using foo1.cloudfront.net
3. I created a new distribution, which got a new .cloudfront.net domain name - let's call it foo2.cloudfront.net

When I tried to assign foo.example.com to the new distribution using **foo2**.cloudfront.net, CloudFront rejected it, because the actual CNAME foo.example.com was pointing at **foo1**.cloudfront.net.

Chicken and egg problem: you can't update foo.example.com to point at foo2.cloudfront.net, because at the time you're creating the new CloudFront distribution, you don't know what (random) URL it will be assigned. At the same time, you can't create the new CloudFront distribution if foo.example.com points at any other *.cloudfront.net distribution.

**The three-step solution** is to remove your CNAME, deploy the CloudFront distribution and then re-create the CNAME when you know that new *.cloudfront.net hostname.

Obviously there is some DNS TTL in play, which somewhat explains why @toreno96 had the issue go away after a little while.

Last contextual info is that I was managing my DNS entirely outside of AWS, so my instance of the problem was completely unrelated to Route53.

Comment: It happens even if you are recreating the same distribution with the same Alternative domain name. I assume that AWS checks the creation date of the CNAME and assumes that if it was created before the distribution it is wrong.

Can't confirm it but it is what makes more sense.

Comment: Are you saying you need to delete the CNAME from the registrar DNS table, wait for that to propagate, THEN create the new distribution and only after that re-create the CNAME in the registrar? I replaced the CNAME value with the new distribution domain from Cloudfront, but it's still not working after 14 hours. I don't think Cloudfront checks for the CNAME creation time because I updated the CNAME after creating my first distribution and it was working after a couple hours. I think there is leftover code in the backend of AWS that needs to be cleared before the new distribution can be used.

Comment: I did the above and it indeed worked. Delete the subdomain from your DNS table in the registrar, wait for that to propagate, then go back to the distribution and add the subdomain. After that you can go back to the DNS table and put in the subdomain again pointing to the new cloudfront domain for the distribution.

Comment: I’m glad it worked for you.